# How to get address of cpp.Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, haxe

Say I have a type in cpp called `MyType`

In haxe:

```
@:native('MyType') extern class MyType {}
typedef MyTypeStar = cpp.Pointer<MyType>;
```

So `var myTypePointer:MyTypeStar` would be equivalent to `MyType*`

Then how to get `MyType**` equivalent from `myTypePointer:MyTypeStar`? Tried `RawPointer.addressOf(myTypePointer.raw)` but doesn't work:

results in native compilation error

```
error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
HXLINE( 198)   ::MyType** cs = &(this->myTypePointer->get_raw());
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: Well seems that `RawPointer.addressOf(myTypePointer)` works...

Comment: It seems that you didn't read the sentence "Warning: This method will only work if a local variable is passed as an argument" in the documentation of `addressOf`.